# DBcontext is getting shared while being registered as Scoped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to migrate from ef6 to ef core and started getting below problems

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.'

on:

```
_dbContext
    .Query<EntityModel>()
    .FromSql(query, new SqlParameter("@userId", userId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This isn't enough information to solve your problem I'm afraid. The error states you are trying to run multiple queries at the same time with a single DbContext. Is this MVC Core? Can you show how you have registered the context in your startup?

Comment: Sounds like your running async operations on your context without awaiting

Comment: @DavidG: Yes its MVC Core, registration code is as below, services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            DbStartup.RegisterContext(services);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this once by adding MultipleActiveResultSets=true to the connectionstring.

Example:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +   
  "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
  "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Just add it in your appsettings.json connectionstring

Comment: I have set MultipleActiveResultSets=True too but it didn't solve the problem...